# subdomain redirection to a subfolder working fine, but not with pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Am using this code to redirect my sub-domain to a folder & it is working fine & if I type
`blog.example.com`

on my browser, it is redirecting me towards my sub-folder but the problem is when I have pages with my URL then it is not redirecting
**like**

`blog.example.com/mypagetitle`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301]
```

I know this is a small problem, but I don't have any experience with this lang.
please help

have tried different things but nothing working like below

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Could you please post your complete htaccess file in your question, in case you haven't posted complete one, thank you.

Comment: Your first rule is correct, have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: yeah am using Incognito Mode, & cleared cache too but still same issue.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 this is the complete code of my htaccess regarding this issue I have few other codes too but that is for other things..